# Replicas in Tekton

Tags: kubernetes, replication, replicaset, tekton

I am quite new to Tekton.

I am facing an issue currently - replication of pods using tekton.

What I want to achieve?

- I want to create a pipeline with two tasks.
- First task creates an echo hello pod
- Second task creates an echo goodbye pod.
- Both pods needs to have 2 replicas.

Error - unknown field "replicas" while running the tasks or pipeline.

I have tried to add replicas in spec section for both tasks and pipeline, but it does not work.
**Any idea where I went wrong?**

Here is my script -
First task -

```
kind: Task
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  replicas: 2
  steps:
    - name: hello
      image: ubuntu
      command:
        - echo
      args:
        - "Hello World!"
```

Second Task

```
kind: Task
metadata:
  name: goodbye
spec:
  replicas: 2
  steps:
    - name: goodbye
      image: ubuntu
      script: |
        #!/bin/bash
        echo "Goodbye World!"
```

Pipeline script -

```
kind: Pipeline
metadata:
  name: hello-goodbye
spec:
  replicas: 2
  tasks:
  - name: hello
    taskRef:
      name: hello
  - name: goodbye
    runAfter:
     - hello
    taskRef:
      name: goodbye
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as "replicas" in Tekton Pipelines.

A Tekton Pipeline is a pipeline of Tasks that execute in a [*directed acyclic graph*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph).

Comment: Thanks @jonas for your reply. 
So in order to create exact same pods in a single Pipeline execution, I will have to create multiple tasks with same config and then run them via Pipelines.. Is my approach reasonable?

Comment: You can use the same Tasks, but you can refer to them in different places in the Pipeline.